# List of comparisons of Merge-Sort recursive alghoritm

Tags: algorithm, sorting

Is there way to write down a list of comparisons of Merge-Sort recursive alghoritm (on a given input) without run it?

I will have an exam where there will be asked something like that, and I couldn't do it on computer.

For example on that input A = { 2, 3, 1, 4, 5, 0, 4, 2, 7, 8 }

Comment: How far did you get? Did you know how a merge-sort algorithm works, if so can you outline the steps you managed?

Comment: There are enough tutorials with examples available online.

Comment: Check out this video, merge sort starts toward the middle http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kgBjXUE_Nwc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this Demo : [MergeSort demo with comparison bounds](http://www.cs.utoronto.ca/~neto/teaching/238/16/mergesort.html)

This page demonstrates MergeSort. At the same time, it shows the number of comparisons actually used, and a worst case upper bound on this number.

Answer (score 0):

You can watch people dancing the Merge Sort algorithm

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XaqR3G_NVoo

Have fun